# Protect Against Other User's Updating My Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I was hoping to get some assistance with my Spring MVC application. This is my first CRUD based application using the Spring Framework, and I am having some concerns around the security of performing some of the CRUD operations on my data. As an example, I navigate to a page where I can click on any of my list of objects from the database, which then using a GET request I obtain the information this specific Object on following "Edit" page.

Although, when redirect to the "Edit" page, in the URL it displays the ID value (`edit?id=1`) for this object which is kind of concern, as a User can manipulate the id parameter passed in the GET request and obtain an object which does not belong to them. How can I protect against this from happening?

In addition to that, once the user guesses the ID value for example, they can manipulate the information and then perform and update on this object even though it does not belong to them. What is the best practice in protecting against such Security? It is probably a simple solution, so all answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement Spring Security for your project. It's the best practice.

Comment: I have this implemented, although what authentication do I require? Can you provide an article or anything as an example?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [HDIV project](http://hdiv.org/) which protects against manipulating references in thie way.

Comment: In Spring Security you have access for the current user.
e.g  
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
Check if this user have access for this action or use @PreAuthorize annotation in your controller.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you're referring to and I have implemented this already. My main concern is that if I have 2 logged in users. 1 User has an article post with the id of 1. The second user can then login, and fetch using the `edit?id=1` which does not belong to them. After that the user which should not be able to manipulate UPDATE or DELETE functions can, because the have the ID of the article already.

Comment: you may need to add a request parameter which is generated server side. The users won't be able to guess it (fast enough). 
edit?id=1&key=AEF8CD12C1

Comment: Could you provide an example of such logic?

Comment: :) don't have an example ready right now. You can find examples where they put a random number in Session (for key generation you can chek org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils)

Comment: Don't fetch records by id only. Add some user unique id to records and get it from security context.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I forgot to update this question as I have successfully resolved this with that exact solution.

Comment: @Maff: You can answer your own question to help future visitors with the same problem.